# SQL SUM of values between two dates calculated fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, between

I have this query, which returns null:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(sales) as [MAT]  
from 
   TABLE2 
where 
   Date1 between CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), DATEADD(MONTH, -11, Date1), 111) and 
                 CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), DATEADD(MONTH, 0, Date1), 111);
```

In the columns, date1 is in the format `YYYY-DD-MM`, which is why I convert it.

I want the sum of the amounts from each date by product (another field) between those two dates.

--UPDATE--

Hi, i already changed the format to `DATETIME` . Now the query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(sales)as [MAT] 
from 
   TABLE2 
where 
   Date1 between DATEADD(MONTH,-11,Date1) and DATEADD(MONTH,0,Date1);
```

It shows me the total amount of all the products, and i want the total for each...any ideas? @DanBracuk

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. ***Please*** use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes

Comment: Looks like you are using the same date field on the left and right side of your BETWEEN expression. I think you want the Date1 variables to the right of the BETWEEN to be literal dates, or a parameter to the query, or some other field.

Comment: It appears to me that date1 is a date/datetime datatype so that part is ok.  It also makes the convert function unnecessary.  @PaulChernoch makes a good point.

Comment: Hi, i already changed the format to DATETIME. Now the query looks like this: 
'SELECT SUM(sales)as [MAT] 
from TABLE2 
where Date1 between DATEADD(MONTH,-11,Date1) and DATEADD(MONTH,0,Date1);'


It shows me the total amount of all the products, and i want the total for each...any ideas? @DanBracuk

Comment: You need to apply Group by like: 'SELECT Product,SUM(sales)as [MAT] from TABLE2 where Date1 between DATEADD(MONTH,-11,Date1) and DATEADD(MONTH,0,Date1) Group by Product;

Answer (score 1):

assuming you've got a column in the table called 'partid', it would be something like this:

```
select partid,sum(sales)
from 
 TABLE2 
where 
 Date1 between DATEADD(MONTH,-11,Date1) and DATEADD(MONTH,0,Date1);
group by partid
```

Answer (score 0):

In Table2 what are the other columns? Specifically is the name of the product identified in the table?

I am pretty sure all you need is a Group By statement at the end. Something like

```
SELECT productName,sum(sales) 
FROM table 2 
WHERE date 1 between DATEADD(MONTH,-11,Date1) and DATEADD(MONTH,0,Date1) 
GROUP BY productName
```

Answer (score 0):

**SQL SUM of values between two dates calculated fields**

```
$sql =  "SELECT  `product_field_name`,
         SUM(CASE WHEN `DATE1_field_name` BETWEEN  '".$MINdate."' and '".$MAXdate."' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS 'MAT'
         FROM TABLE_name 
         GROUP BY `product_field_name`";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need sum of the values for each date by product between those two dates, you shoul add date and product fields as a group by;

```
SELECT 
   Date1, product, SUM(sales)as [MAT] 
from 
   TABLE2 
where 
   Date1 between DATEADD(MONTH,-11,Date1) and DATEADD(MONTH,0,Date1)
group by Date1, product;
```