# Add values between a date range

Tags: java

Trying to write a program where I have some data of holdings in between date ranges in database. There might be two rows or three rows in between that date range. Each row has a holding value and I need to add each value in that date range. Can anyone suggest to me the solution? I tried this but it isn't working.

```
for(int i=0;i<filteredStartDate.size();i++) {
    Long sum = null;
    if(filteredStartDate.get(i).isBefore((ChronoLocalDate) filteredEndDate)) {
         sum = sum+listHoldingsDBRecords.get(i).getHoldings();
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Your *BEST* bet would probably be if you could let the *DATABASE* do this for you.  Here's some example SQL:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17622200/421195

Comment: What does getHoldings return?  What are your dates like (LocalDate?).  Do you expect multiple sums for each holding or a single sum.  More information would be helpful.  And initialize sum to 0.  And I suggest using `long`, and not `Long`.  And put sum outside the loop.  Otherwise you keep resetting it.

Comment: Holdings is a long value. Say for example we have 5 holding values between Jan 1 and Jan 31 then I need to add those 5 values. Yes, it is a Local Date.

Comment: So what isn't working with your current method?  What's the data, what are you getting, and what do you expect to get?  And what about @paulsm4 suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated what I believe to be your situation.  I am using a `record` for the Holdings.

```
public class SumDateRange {
    record Holdings(long getHoldings) {
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Holdings> listHoldingsDBRecords =
                List.of(new Holdings(10), new Holdings(20),
                        new Holdings(30), new Holdings(140),
                        new Holdings(150), new Holdings(160));
        
        List<LocalDate> filteredStartDate =
                List.of(LocalDate.parse("2022-01-15"),
                        LocalDate.parse("2022-01-20"),
                        LocalDate.parse("2022-01-30"),
                        LocalDate.parse("2022-02-15"),
                        LocalDate.parse("2022-02-15"),
                        LocalDate.parse("2022-02-15"));
        
        LocalDate filteredEndDate = LocalDate.parse("2022-01-31");
        
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < filteredStartDate.size(); i++) {
            if (filteredStartDate.get(i).isBefore(filteredEndDate)) {
                sum = sum
                        + listHoldingsDBRecords.get(i).getHoldings();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

prints

```
60
```

Remember that any date before the end date is valid.  So perhaps you need a minimum acceptable date and check for within a range:

```
if (filteredStartDate.get(i).isAfter(minimumAcceptableDate) && 
    filteredStartDate.get(i).isBefore(filteredEndDate)) {
```

But the above depends entirely on your ultimate goal and the data involved.

Comment: Your code is working but my expected result is not what I want. I got three dates 2021-01-30
2022-01-30
9999-12-31 and the holdings expected for these dates is 135515288
134543446
134543446 however, the output I got using this code is 135515288
270058734
404602180 I want the addition results separately.

Comment: I appreciate the accept but apparently I haven't solved your problem.  Given the description in the question I am not certain what you want.  If you edit your question and provide some examples of the data and the expected results I may be able to help.  In the sample data, It is important to have multiple holdings for each date range, the actual holding values, and the expected sums for each.  And are you really using a range of dates that the holdings fall between or the holdings for a specific date that need to be summed?

Comment: It also appears that your list of holdings must be in sync with your list of dates.  If I am correct, this could lead to problems.  A better way would be to have the `Holdings class` also contain the dates that apply to it.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, generally best to that kind of work on the database. But your question is about Java, so here goes.

Regarding your use of `ChronoLocalDate`, if you study the Javadoc you’ll see that the abstract classes, interfaces, and superclasses are *not* intended for app development in *java.time*, generally. Those are for internal use by *java.time* itself, and for third parties implementing a chronology for the *java.time* framework.

To track a date range as a pair of dates, I suggest adding the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. That library offers the [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class to represent a pair of `LocalDate` objects. The class offers handy methods such as `contains`, `abuts`, etc.

To represent your data in Java, define a map with `LocalDateRange` as the key, and a `List` of your holding numbers. After map, you can loop on he entries to report a sum of each list.

```
Map< LocalDateRange , List< BigDecimal > > map = … ;
```

This structure is known as a [*multimap*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap), meaning each key maps to a collection of multiple values rather than to a single value.

All this has been covered many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.